# Apache Thrift Python-Java 'Connection Refused'

Tags: java, python, windows, networking, thrift

I've recently tried to connect Python to Java using Thrift.

I've written a server on Python (PyPy). I've also written a reference client which works.

Then I've written a Java client which produces only a 'Connection refused' exception.

What's wrong with this? (Recently I've also found a closed issue featuring this problem https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1888)

PS. Used Thrift 0.9 release, PyPy 2.0 beta 2, Java 1.7.0_11

*test.thrift*

```
namespace java com.test
namespace python test

service TestPing {
   void ping()
}
```

*Python server code*

```
class TestPingHandler:
  def ping(self):
    pass

handler = TestPingHandler()
processor = TestPing.Processor(handler)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port=9091)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()

server = TServer.TThreadedServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

print 'Starting the server...' 
server.serve()
print 'done.'
```

*Java client code*

```
TTransport transport;
transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9091);
transport.open();
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
client = new TestPing.Client(protocol);
client.ping();
```

*Reference Python client code*

```
transport = TSocket.TSocket('localhost', 9091)
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
client = TestPing.Client(protocol)
transport.open()
client.ping()
transport.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Replacing "localhost" with the ip fixed it.

The reason was: Python used TCPV6, where Java used TCP.

Python:
    `transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(host="127.0.0.1", port = 9091)`

Java:
    `transport = new TSocket("127.0.0.1", 9091);`

Answer (score 0):

```
transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9091);
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
transport.open();

This should work...
```